# .env File or a Config Class

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables, config

Is there a reason why I would use the following:

```
from flask import Flask
import stripe

class Config():
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = 'stripe-secret-key'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
stripe.api_key = app.config['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
```

rather than populating the `.env` file with `export STRIPE_SECRET_KEY="stripe-secret-key"` and then using:

```
from environs import Env
from flask import Flask
import stripe

env = Env()
env.read_env()
stripe.api_key = env.str('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY')
```

i.e. why wouldn't I just store all environment variables in the `Config` class, rather than a `.env` file? Is it more secure to use a `.env` file?

Thanks for any help here :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see three reasons that would justify using `.env`:

1. Convention. `.env` is a name of a file that, by convention stores environment variables
2. Using `class Config` makes it Python-specific and harder to parse by other languages

but the most important reason, in my opinion is:

3. `.env` file is usually (by default) included in [.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore) files which protects you from accidentally committing (and pushing) sensitive information

Comment: Can hackers who gain access to your server find your .env file and extract passwords? i.e. if your directory structure is: `server/app/ + server/.env + server/wsgi.py` can anyone see the contents of the .env file? Or do you have change the permissions of the file?

Comment: Depends on their access level and the file permissions. If the file is only readable by you (i.e. your linux user) and a malicious user accessed your server using someone else's identity - you should be safe. If a malicious user has access to `root` there is very little you can do.

Answer (score 3):

It is more secure. `config.py` is a part of your code, your app woudn't work without it. So if you publish code of your app or share it with a college, you're supposed to share `config.py` too. But you're not supposed to pulish your env file. And when someone runs your code, they can easily create their own env file by looking at variables in `config.py`. It's the way of telling people what config variables are expected in your app without compromising security of your own instance of that app.